# Inserting values from my TextField in Java into a database

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, sql-insert, actionevent

I'm a newbie here and I would have one question that I'm having hard times getting an answer to. I need to set up a program in  Java that could enable the user to insert values into a database based on what they type in the TextField. Here are the 3 classes that I've created:

```
public class Odabrani{

    public int id;
    String ime;
    String prezime;

        public Odabrani(int id, String ime, String prezime){

            this.id=id;
            this.ime=ime;
            this.prezime=prezime;


        }
}


import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



    public class MySQL{ 
        public static Connection connect() throws InstantiationException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prodavnica", "root", "");
            return conn;
        }
    public static void Obrisi(int id) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Connection conn = connect();
        Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("delete from prodavac where id = " + id);
        conn.close();
    }


    public static List<Prodavac> GetProdavci() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Connection conn = connect();
    Statement st = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    st.executeQuery("select * from prodavac");
    ResultSet rs = st.getResultSet();
    List<Prodavac> pr = new ArrayList<Prodavac>();
    while(rs.next()){
        pr.add(new Prodavac(rs.getInt(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));
        //String ime = rs.getString(2);

    }
    conn.close();
        return pr;

        }

    public static void Dodaj(String ime, String prezime) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Connection conn = connect();
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into prodavac (id, ime, prezime) values (null,' ,' ) + ime, prezime;");
        conn.close();
    }


    }



import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author v
 */
**public class Main** {
       static TextField unos;
       public static Prodavac odabrani_prodavac;
       public static JComboBox c;
       public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException{
        Frame f = new Frame("Biblioteka");
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setLocation(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
        c = new JComboBox();
        List l = new List();
        unos = new TextField(20);
        f.add(unos);

        unos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    MySQL.Dodaj(odabrani_prodavac.ime, odabrani_prodavac.prezime);
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });




        Button b = new Button("obrisi");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if(odabrani_prodavac!=null)
                   try {
                       MySQL.Obrisi(odabrani_prodavac.id);
                       c.removeAllItems();
                       java.util.List<Prodavac> prlist = MySQL.GetProdavci();
                        for(Prodavac p: prlist)
                            c.addItem(p);

                   } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   } catch (SQLException ex) {
                       Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }
               }
           });

        java.util.List<Prodavac> prlist = MySQL.GetProdavci();
        for(Prodavac p: prlist)
               c.addItem(p);
        f.add(c);
        f.add(b);
        c.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

               @Override
               public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                   if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                    Prodavac p = (Prodavac)e.getItem();
                    odabrani_prodavac = p;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Odabrali ste: " + p.toString());
                   }
               }
           });





       }
}
```

Now, if you pay attention to this you can see that both the delete() and gettAll() methods work perfect but it's the insert method(s) that bother me. How do I play around this code in question so the text that user types in gets stored into a database. Please advise. Thank You! Ivan

Comment: Your `Insert` statement has a syntax error, please re-read the syntax of the same.

Comment: As a side note, you should just post the code that's relevant to the problem.  In your case, you mentioned the "insert method(s)".  It's much easier to troubleshoot smaller code snippets...

Comment: Ok, here's the code in question which I believe the errors might be coming from:

Comment: The code is too long to throw in but then again:

        unos = new TextField(20);
        f.add(unos);
        Button a = new Button("insert");
        f.add(a);

a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(unos!=null)
/*this is where some piece of code should come into view. Basically it should read like if there's any text typed in the textfield put it into a database by calling insert method in MySQL class: MySQL.Dodaj(String ime, String prezime).How do I get to get the text in textfield 2B stored in database?*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your insert statement to

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into prodavac (id, ime, prezime) values (null,'"+ime+"','"+prezime+"'" );
```

Comment: Hello, your code appears to me OK but my program is still throwing errors at me, it might have something to do with the way the input text is placed into a database, the action event in the main class? I have no idea?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:47)
 at java.awt.TextField.processActionEvent(TextField.java:594)
 at java.awt.TextField.processEvent(TextField.java:562)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)

Comment: at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

Comment: Did you try this `PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into prodavac (ime, prezime) values ('"+ime+"','"+prezime+"'" );`

Answer (score 1):

`PreparedStatement` provides placeholder characters to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks as well as handle as the insertion of any quotes that may be required. Also if `id` is an *auto increment* field, you can omit this from the `SQL`:

```
PreparedStatement pst = 
    conn.prepareStatement("insert into prodavac (ime, prezime) values (?, ?)");
pst.setString(1, ime);
pst.setString(2, prezime);
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yes, the auto_increment was put on id column so all I have to do is put both the name and surname in it but even after I apply your code the program is still not working, hmm?

Comment: OK guys, thank you for your assistance this puzzle has been finally pieced together. The major problem stemmed from my inability to get the text from the text filed and then insert it into the table. So what I did I put up another textField where I'll be getting both the name and surname input from, put them as parameters in MySQL.Dodaj() method and moved forward from there. My SQL was asking me to insert wildcards(?,?,?) representing the user input so this program of mine works for me perfect now. Thank you all for your assistance.